# Super-capacitors to heat resistive wire

Tags: heat, constant-current, supercapacitor

I am looking for help/insight into the feasibility of using the stored energy in supercaps to heat a short length of nichrome wire, or a vape coil.

I have nichrome wire that is 0.040 size, at 0.408 ohms/foot, and the vape coils I purchased are 1.8 ohms. My goal is to be able to use the energy in a store supercap to heat the resistance wire to about 500 C (or hot enough to light a cigarette) for about 1-2 seconds.

I used my bench power supply to charge a 5.5 V 1 F cap, and after it was charged, I tried to discharge it through one of the vape coils, and I watched the voltage drop to 0 on my multimeter, but the coil did not warm up.

1. Some questions - Is it feasible to heat resistance wire as mentioned by discharging a supercap through the wire?
2. Or are more components needed (such as a constant current source powered by the cap to heat the wire, or to control the discharge through a mosfet or something prior to the coil? Any circuits provided are appreciated.
3. Is this totally the wrong application of supercaps, and I should be looking at Li batteries?

Can anyone at least point me to some projects/literature that can help my understanding of the problem and possible solutions?

Comment: Too much ESR in a supercap.

Comment: Thanks! Is it feasible to do this with normal low ESR caps, or is the energy storage not enough?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, typical coil voltage for vape coils is around 4 V. That means the coil consumes P=V²/R = 4²x1.8 = 9 W. In order to run it for 2 seconds, you then need 9x2=18 Ws = 18 J of energy in the capacitor.

For 18 Ws (or J) in a 5.5 V capacitor, you will need C=Q/V = 18/5.5 = 3.3 F.
Although, you probably won't be able to use all the energy in the supercap. If you want to connect the coil directly to the capacitor, it must not discharge too much (because at lower voltage the power will be insufficient), so you will probably need 3-4 times my calculated capacitance. So at least 10 F or so.

So if you connect ten of those capacitors in parallell, it might work. Then the ESR might also be low enough (depending on the model of capacitor).

Comment: One W \$ \times\$ s is a [Joule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule)

Comment: @DDuck That is true, but it is just as much a Ws. Which one of them is mode preferable depends on the context, and here I found Ws to be more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your capacitor dumps all its energy into your nichrome wire:
0.04mm diameter * 1344mm length (from coil resistance) = 1.689mm^3
At 8.2 g/cm^3, coil weight is 0.0138g and at 0.48 J/g*C, the 15.125J in your capacitor would only raise the temperature 228C.  However, as @Andy aka points out, the ESR is robbing you of a bunch of that.

Comment: Hi, I should have been more clear, I purchased some vape coils, they are 1.8 ohms, I do not know the rest of the specs... I used one of these coils as stated above. 

I also have a ton of nichrome wire, size 0.040 (in inches I think not mm?) B&S 18 size, at 0.408 ohms/foot that I can use to make my own resistive heating elements, but have not done so yet. 

Thank you for your help though, it seems with the set up I currently have there is not enough capacitance, and also the ESR is preventing this from working. I just found some low ESR caps that I can bank at 5.5V at 10 F, I can try them?

Comment: I think the 18 is the gauge, and 18 gauge is 0.048"... not sure why my wire says 0.040". I just double checked with calipers, and the nichrome wire is 0.040", very different than 0.04 mm, and smaller than 18 gauge, unless B&S is some special type of gauge measurement.  

Just as an aside, I hate imperial measurements and wish everything in the US was metric.

Comment: LOL Apparently Brown and Sharpe came up with their own Gauge system which is different than AWG (American Wire Gauge)... I just checked a table, 18 B&S Gauge does correspond to 0.040", not 0.048" as if it were AWG....